# Best way to initialize array with 1 or more items

Tags: php

I'm setting the value of the variable as a array.

Based on some conditions I have to initialize wether

```
array('a', 'b');
```

or

```
array('a', 'b', 'c');
```

So what is the best way?

Should we write

```
$a = array('a', 'b');

if($b > 0) {

    $a[] = 'c'?

}
```

or

```
if($b > 0) {

    $a = array('a', 'b', 'c');

} else {

    $a = array('a', 'b');

}
```

First one looks more nice for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we should define what is "best". For me best is:

1. Executes fast.
2. Done the "right" way.
3. Easy to read.

Both are almost identical compared as speed of execution (I did a quick test with 1mil iterations), so no clear winner here.

Both examples are easy to read, however I'll stick with the first one, because if for some reason you are requested to add "a1" to the array, you'll end having to change one line of code, not two.

EDIT: Here is the code I ran ($b = 0 and $b = 1 doesn't change it much.:
EDIT2: Seems my first benchmark was wrong. Here is a second one doing only one iteration. Clearly the second block of code executes faster.

```php
$b = 1;

$t = microtime(true);

$a = array('a', 'b');
if($b > 0) {
    $a[] = 'c';
}

printf("%f\n", microtime(true)-$t);


$t = microtime(true);

if($b > 0) {
    $a = array('a', 'b', 'c');
} else {
    $a = array('a', 'b');
    $a[] = 'c';
}

printf("%f\n", microtime(true)-$t);
```

Output:

```
0.000017
0.000003
```

Comment: Please don't benchmark like this because it's very inconsistent.

Comment: I got `3.7593920230865` for the first and `1.9740960597992` for the second.

Comment: Here it goes: http://codepad.org/b2tXJiOP. By doing it like this, you make sure you use the CPU cycles in a distributed manner, instead of running the first or second experiment while the CPU is more busy doing something else and running the other experiment when the CPU is idle.

Comment: @mspasov: I think otherwise, you should run as much iterations as you can so you end up with a consistent average.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the first option is the best since it follows the DRY and the divide and conquer principles.

Here is [another benchmark](http://ideone.com/ydqRu) that shows that the fist approach is on average just 13.5% slower.

Comment: Thanks for benchmarking. I also prefer 1st varianat, it's realy more dry.